# Snowflake shows 'Invalid date' in TIMESTAMP_NTZ column

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In our Snowflake Data Warehouse instance, when loading data from a stage into a table using a `COPY INTO` DDL statement, some records in a timestamp_ntz column display a value of `Invalid date` in the Snowflake UI.

These `Invalid date` values in the timestamp_ntz columns have the following qualities:

- they are not NULL
- they seem to be considered as always greater than the current timestamp, and this attribute can be used to filter them, eg. `WHERE strange_timestamp_col > current_timestamp()`
- they are not something "on the front-end" ie. in the Snowflake UI - they break other clients using the data in Snowflake

We would expect an invalid data format to return an error when attempting to execute the `COPY INTO` DDL statement; instead these nefarious pseudo-timestamps with strange properties are inserted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We discovered that some of the unix timestamp values in our staged parquet files were formatted as integers and some as strings!

The solution is to always cast the column to VARCHAR and then to TIMESTAMP_NTZ.

Example using a unix timestamp:

`SELECT 1620502461213752::timestamp_ntz;` -> `Invalid date`

`SELECT 1620502461213752::varchar::timestamp_ntz;` -> `2021-05-08 19:34:21.213`

`SELECT '1620502461213752'::timestamp_ntz;` -> `2021-05-08 19:34:21.213`

This seems to be because `timestamp_ntz` only accepts integer epoch timestamps in milliseconds (eg. 1620502461213).

However, when the integer is cast to `varchar` first, then `timestamp_ntz` correctly interprets the epoch timestamp in microseconds (eg. 1620502461213752). This likely applies to timestamps in nanoseconds as well, although I did not confirm that case.

So it seems that `Invalid date` is a strange front-end issue for timestamps far in the future, created by misidentifying epoch timestamp units.

Comment: Just to clarify are you saying the files import fine but when you look at the data in the final table it says 'invalid date'? That doesn't sound very reliable!

Comment: I completely agree; it's a very unreliable experience. We would expect invalid data formats throw errors when attempting the `COPY INTO` DDL. Unfortunately that did not happen, and we experienced these weird `Invalid date` values in the timestamp_ntz column.